# Converting the rows of panda data frame into columns

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe, reshape

having panda data frame with two like this:

```
Key Value
A    2
A    6
B    7
A    1
B    3
B    4
A    2
```

How can I reshape in such a way that it looks like:

```
A B
2 7
6 3
1 4
2 NaN
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use  `groupby` with `apply` for creating new `index` values:

```
df = df.groupby('Key').Value.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.values)).unstack(0)
print (df)
Key  A  B
0    2  7
1    6  3
2    1  4
3    2  0
```

Another solution with [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot.html) and creating new `index` values by [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
df = pd.pivot(index = df.groupby('Key').cumcount(), columns=df['Key'], values=df['Value'])
print (df)
Key  A  B
0    2  7
1    6  3
2    1  4
3    2  0
```

---

```
df1 = df.groupby('Key').Value.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.values)).unstack(0)
print (df1)
Key    A    B
0    2.0  7.0
1    6.0  3.0
2    1.0  4.0
3    2.0  NaN

df2 = pd.pivot(index = df.groupby('Key').cumcount(), columns=df['Key'], values=df['Value'])
print (df2)
Key    A    B
0    2.0  7.0
1    6.0  3.0
2    1.0  4.0
3    2.0  NaN
```

Comment: I am editing my question to accommodate the case where the number of A's is less than B's.

Comment: For me it works, see edit. But if need `int` values together with `NaN`, it is impossible in pandas. Solution is replace `NaN` to some values like `0` - `print (df1.fillna(0).astype(int))`

Comment: You can check [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/gotchas.html#na-type-promotions) - `integer  cast to float64`

Answer (score 2):

## `pandas`

using `pd.concat` with a list comprehension and `np.unique`

```
s = pd.Series(df.Value.values, df.Key.values)
u = np.unique(s.index.values).tolist()
pd.concat([s.loc[k].reset_index(drop=True) for k in u], axis=1, keys=u)

   A    B
0  2  7.0
1  6  3.0
2  1  4.0
3  2  NaN
```

## `numpy`

```
# np.unique can return value counts and an inverse array
# the inverse array will be very helpful in slicing the final
# array we are trying to fill
u, inv, c = np.unique(df.Key.values, return_inverse=True, return_counts=True)

# construct empty array to fill with values
# number of rows equal to the maximum value count
# number of columns equal to the number of unique values
new = np.empty((c.max(), len(u)), dtype=np.float)
new.fill(np.nan)

# construct handy cumulative count per unique value
rows = np.arange(len(inv)) - np.append(0, c[:-1]).repeat(c)

# use slicing arrays to fill empty array
new[rows, inv] = df.Value.values

pd.DataFrame(new, np.arange(c.max()), u)

   A    B
0  2  7.0
1  6  3.0
2  1  4.0
3  2  NaN
```

---

***time test***

[image]